# Email contact form extra text

Tags: php

```
<?php


if($_POST["message"]) {


mail("myemailadress@gmail.com", "Haar van Shar contact formulier",


$_POST"Name"["message"]);


}


?>
```

Hi guys I have this little Php code in my website. At the name part in this code I want to have in the Email that it sends Name: "message". But on the way I have done this right now it doesn't work. So does anyone know how to get this result?

Comment: I’m not certain what your problem is or what you are trying to do. Can you explain further? What is the “name part”? It might help to use parameter names from the documentation, too: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: `$_POST"Name"["message"])` isn't valid PHP syntax.

Comment: You probably meant something like: `"Name: ".$_POST["message"]` I suspect.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the work. Pay attention to the third mail parameter, your code has wrong syntax.

```
<?php    
if ($_POST["message"]) {
    mail(
        "myemailadress@gmail.com", 
        "Haar van Shar contact formulier",
        "Name: " . $_POST["message"]
    );    
}    
?>
```